# Why does grep ignore the shell variable containing directories to be ignored?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

On Mac OS X, I have a bash script like this:

```
# Directories excluded from grep go here.
EXCLUDEDIR="--exclude-dir={node_modules,.git,tmp,angular*,icons,server,coffee}"

# This grep needs to include one line below the hit.
grep -iIrn -A1 $EXCLUDEDIR -e "class=[\"\']title[\"\']>$" -e "<div class=\"content" . > microcopy.txt
```

but it seems to be ignoring `$EXCLUDEDIR`. If I simply use the `--exclude-dir` directly, it works. Why won't it expand the variable and work right?

Comment: Do you have any directories whose names start with `angular` and which have spaces in them?

Comment: @KyleStrand I do not have any directory names with spaces; I suspect the cause is as given below by tripleee.

Comment: Ah. Yep, that'll do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The braces are technically an error.  When they are in a variable, they are included verbatim, while when you type them directly as part of the command, Bash performs brace expansion, and effectively removes the braces from your expression.

```
bash$ echo --exclude-dir=moo{bar,baz}
--exclude-dir=moobar --exclude-dir=moobaz

bash$ x='moo{bar,baz}'
bash$ echo --exclude-dir=$x
--exclude-dir=moo{bar,baz}
```

The (not so simple) workaround is to list your parameters explicitly instead.  This can be somewhat simplified by using an array to list the directory names you want to exclude (but this is not portable to legacy `/bin/sh`).

```
x=(node_modules .git tmp angular\* icons server coffee)
EXCLUDEDIR="${x[@]/#/--exclude-dir=}"
```

The backslash in `angular\*` is to pass this wildcard expression through to `grep` unexpanded -- if the shell would expand the variable, `grep` would not exclude directories matching the wildcard expression in subdirectories (unless they conveniently happened to match one of the expanded values in the current directory).  If you have `nullglob` in effect, an unescaped wildcard would simply disappear from the lists.

Comment: If he intends on excluding all directories whose names begin with "angular" then that token (word) shouldn't be quoted, nor should the asterisk be backslash-escaped.

Comment: @klf Depends.  The shell will expand an unquoted `angular*` to any and all matches in the current directory when the array is assigned.  If there are none, and `nullglob` is not in effect, it will be left with an asterisk. If `nullglob` is in effect, it will be removed, unless there are matches in the local directory, in which case they will be expanded; but then, any matches in subdirectories will not be included.  So if you have `angular1` and `subdir/angular2` then `subdir/angular2` will not be excluded in this scenario.

Comment: Probably listing the parameters explicitly is the simplest and safest way if a variable won't work in this case.

Comment: No, but you can.  Updated the answer to do the Right Thing.  Thanks for prodding.

Answer (score 2):

@tripleee correctly describes the problem, but there are two workarounds that I think are simpler (and, I think, more portable) than using an array: use `eval` in the `git` command, or use `echo` in the variable assignment itself. **The `echo` method is preferable.**

## Using `eval`

```
# Directories excluded from grep go here.
EXCLUDEDIR="--exclude-dir={node_modules,.git,tmp,angular*,icons,server,coffee}"

# This grep needs to include one line below the hit.
eval grep -iIrn -A1 $EXCLUDEDIR # .... etc
```

This causes the braces to be expanded as if they had been typed literally. Note, however, that it may have some unintended side-effects if you're not careful; for instance, you may need to add some extra `\`'s to escape quotes and `$`-signs.

## Using `echo`

This is potentially safer than `eval`, since you won't accidentally execute code hidden in the `EXCLUDEDIR` variable.

```
# Directories excluded from grep go here.
EXCLUDEDIR="$(echo --exclude-dir={node_modules,.git,tmp,angular*,icons,server,coffee})"

# This grep needs to include one line below the hit.
grep -iIrn -A1 $EXCLUDEDIR # .... etc
```

Comment: Not having very deep knowledge of `eval` and its effects on everything else in that command (or that might end up on that command), I hesitate. I just don't have a good-enough understanding of what unwanted consequences might arise.

Comment: Fair enough. `eval` basically just adds a second iteration of the interpolation that Bash performs before passing the command to `grep`. The main problem I think you might run into is that after the first evaluation, quoted tokens are now unquoted, so you might have to escape or double-quote things like `$` inside arguments. You can play around with it pretty simply by doing an `eval echo grep`, though. I think this usage is safe since you control the `EXCLUDEDIR` variable, and set it immediately before the `eval`.

Comment: @user766353 I've added a solution that uses `$()` and `echo` instead of `eval`